# Autosize javafx window to scenebuilder pref width and height?

Tags: java, javafx

my question is simple. Is there a way to get the preferred width and height from scenebuilder[image]

And not have to update my Start method with that exact resolution. Is there some auto keyword?

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root,364,635);
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `Scene` to be initialized with the preferred size of its content don't explicitly set the size during construction. From the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html) of `Scene`:

> The scene's size may be initialized by the application during construction. If no size is specified, the scene will automatically compute its initial size based on the preferred size of its content. If only one dimension is specified, the other dimension is computed using the specified dimension, respecting content bias of a root.

In your case, simply use:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

If you must specify the width and height during construction, for instance to set the depth buffer and/or anti-aliasing, use a negative number (e.g. `-1`) for the width and height.

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, -1, -1, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
```

That will cause the `Scene` to still use the preferred size of its content<sup>1</sup>. Note you only need to deal with depth buffering/anti-aliasing if using 3D features (read the linked documentation for more information).

---

<sup>1. Couldn't find documentation about this. However, if I understood the implementation correctly, using negative numbers is the same as not setting the dimension.</sup>

Comment: I am new to JavaFX and I did not know the overloaded ways to instantiate. I was under the impression from the book I'm reading that a resolution  in the form of 2 parameters was required. This answered my question perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling the method sizeToScene on your stage object.

You can read it in docs...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene--

Edit:
scene parameters for height and width should be removed.

Comment: This did not work for me unfortunately. I tried calling primaryStage.sizeToScene(); But it had no effect. I was really hoping I could pass something as a parameter instead of a number in my scene instantiation.

Comment: you should remove scene parameters for height and width.